# Preservice git history while converting VB to C#

Tags: c#, git, vb.net, file-conversion, git-rewrite-history

I've used [fishcodelib's Convert .Net](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fishcodelib.ConvertNETBasedonNET45) library to convert a VB-project to C#. It creates C#-files next to the vb ones. I've deleted the vb-ones and checked everything in.

[image: Files are seen as deleted/added]

I've got everything working, but now if I view a files history, it starts with my conversion.
I would have liked it better if GIT saw this edits as renames followed by edits, so the history for each file before, during and after the conversion, was preserved.

Is there a way to fix this retroactively, before pushing my changes to master?
(There's about 300 code files, so I'd like some tips on minimizing the amount of manual work)

I *COULD* use this approach:

1. Save the files in the current branch
2. Create a new branch from master
3. Rename every vb file to cs
4. Check this in
5. Overwrite everything with the saved files
6. Check this in

Would this work and/or is there a smarter approach?

*edit*

I tried this approach and even though my local visual studio sees the correct history, the pull request still doesn't.

The first update correctly recognises the rename (and sometimes an edit) but the pull request as a whole shows deleted and added files. I'm hoping things will turn out OK after merge; maybe it's assuming a squash merge.

[image: The first update]

Comment: You _can't_ force git to see something as a rename. The thing is that git does **not** track renames. It infers that **after the fact** when an operation (like blaming) takes place, and this is done by comparing contents of files between 2 commits.... if the differences are over a threshold, git assumes the files are not the same.... and this threshold value can be changed on a per-operation basis.

Comment: Your recipe would help git... though it won't be something to show at _the louvre_... but that was not your intent in the first place, right?. :-)